# Show row based on cell value - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rows, show

I'm using the following code to hide rows based on cell value:

```
Sub HideN()

Dim RowCnt As Long, uRng As Range

BeginRow = 8
EndRow = 232
ChkCol = 6

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
         If uRng Is Nothing Then
          Set uRng = Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)
         Else
          Set uRng = Union(uRng, Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol))
         End If

        End If
    Next RowCnt

 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

What do I have to modify if I also want to unhide the rows where the cell value is 1?

Thanks in advance!

MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an additional `If` statement, no?:

```
Sub HideN()

Dim RowCnt As Long, uRng As Range

BeginRow = 8
EndRow = 232
chkcol = 6

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, chkcol).Value = 0 Then
        If uRng Is Nothing Then
            Set uRng = Cells(RowCnt, chkcol)
        Else
            Set uRng = Union(uRng, Cells(RowCnt, chkcol))
        End If
    End If
    If Cells(RowCnt, chkcol).Value = 1 Then ' This is the new line to add
        Rows(RowCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next RowCnt

If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This will hide all that are 0 and unhide all others.

```
Sub HideN()

Dim RowCnt As Long
Dim BeginRow&, EndRow&, ChkCol&

BeginRow = 8
EndRow = 232
ChkCol = 6

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        Rows(RowCnt).Hidden = Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0
    Next RowCnt



End Sub
```

Of course you can do the same with a filter.

Comment: An excellent example of setting a boolean value to the result of a boolean expression - +1